# How do I write a regular expression that matches text that does not contain all caps?

Tags: asp.net, regex, forms, validation

I'm using the ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator

I need a regular expression to keep users who fill out a form from using all caps.

For example, if they write their name:

Bob JONES or BOB JONES or BOB JOnes or whatever, it will not match.

I am able to match all caps with this regular expression:

`[A-Z]{2,10}`

But the RegularExpressionValidator requires me to match valid text, not invalid text.

Comment: What languages will this be before? What letters could be in the names? Anything outside A-Z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have each word have no more than 1 capital letter in a row at a time, and assuming it's okay to restrict to ASCII letters, try something like this:

```
^(?:[a-z]|[A-Z](?![A-Z])|['-])+$
```

In other words, the string must be entirely composed of either lowercase letters, or uppercase letters not followed by another uppercase letter.

This works for single words. For multiple words (like a full name, first and last), simply add a space to the alternation:

```
^(?:[a-z]|[A-Z](?![A-Z])|[\s'-])+$
```

*(Edited to allow apostrophe and hyphen punctuation)*

Answer (score 1):

use this Regex: @"^[^A-Z]*$" It will match anything that not contains upper case characters.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression `^[a-z ]+$`
if you want catch names like `Bob Jones` use this one `^([A-Z][a-z ]+)+$`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm just stating the obvious, but couldn't you just to myVar.string.toLower before doing the Compare?

Comment: The OP is using a part of ASP.NET which automatically validates form content. With this, one declares regular expressions for validation in a configuration file; it is not possible to change how the validation actually occurs. So it comes down to either having a suitable regex or writing validation code by hand, which is much more tedious. The OP's requirements are not super clear from the question, but I think I have inferred what s/he basically wants.

Comment: No because I don't want all lower case, I just don't want all caps.  For example, my last name has two capital letters, but not together, so I don't want to eliminate those kinds of names. Half the users here love to use all caps on forms, so they'll go JO ANN in the fname field and RHYMES in the lname, or whatever. Rather than Jo Ann, etc..